# Unused factor levels not dropped after subsetting?

Tags: r, subset, r-factor

I have a variable `df1$StudyAreaVisitNote` which I turn into a factor. But when I subsetted the `df1` into `BS` this variable did not remain a factor:  using the table( ) function on the subsetted data would show results that seemed to be what should be returned if `table()` was run on the original data?

Why does this happen?

The two workarounds I found were:

1. export the subsetted data and re-import
2. after subsetting, designate the column as a factor again

Code:

```
# My dataset can be found here: http://textuploader.com/9tx5  (I'm sure there's a better way to host it, but I'm new, sorry!)
# Load Initial Dataset (df1)
df1 <- read.csv("/Users/user/Desktop/untitled folder/pre_subset.csv", header=TRUE,sep=",")

# Make both columns factors
df1$Trap.Type <- factor(df1$Trap.Type)
df1$StudyAreaVisitNote <-factor(df1$StudyAreaVisitNote)

# Subset out site of interest
BS <- subset(df1, Trap.Type=="HR-BA-BS")

# Export to Excel, save as CSV after it's in excel
library(WriteXLS)
 WriteXLS("BS", ExcelFileName = "/Users/user/Desktop/test.xlsx", col.names = TRUE, AdjWidth = TRUE, BoldHeaderRow = TRUE, FreezeRow = 1)


# Load second Dataset (df2)
df2 <- read.csv("/Users/user/Desktop/untitled folder/post_subset.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")

# both datasets should be identical, and they are superficially, but...
# Have a look at df2
summary(df2$StudyAreaVisitNote)  # Looks good, only counts levels that are present

# Now, look at BS from df1
summary(BS$StudyAreaVisitNote)  # sessions not present in the subsetted data (but present in df1?) are included???

# Make BS$StudyAreaVisitNote a factor...Again??
BS$StudyAreaVisitNote <- factor(BS$StudyAreaVisitNote)

# Try line 31 again
summary(BS$StudyAreaVisitNote) # this time it works, why is factor not carried through during subset?
```

Comment: I retitled your question **"Why are unused factor levels not dropped after subsetting?"**. Don't say 'fields' or 'sessions' if you mean 'levels'. Don't say "did not remain a factor... strange results", that doesn't tell us anything. If you want to see if it was still a factor, use `str()`. As a bonus `str()` also tells you its levels. You would have spotted the issue instantly.

Comment: Don't post links to your dataset on third-party sites (it's now 403 expired), but even if not it would be clearer and simpler and self-contains if you used `dput()` and pasted it into the question. Since we can't reproduce th edata, we can't reproduce your code; it would have been clearer if you posted the `summary()/table()` output for us.

Comment: *"strange results that seemed to be what should be returned if table() was run on the original data??"* = *"The table contained all the factor levels from the original, I want the levels unused in the subset to be dropped"*. Anyway you can do that with `tab <- table(...); tab[tab > 0]`

Comment: Just because it has extraneous levels, don't accuse it of not being a factor :-)

Comment: *"Workaround: export and re-import"* is a red herring, just use [`factor(..., levels=..., exclude=...)`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/factor.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A factor is maintained a factor even after subsetting. I'm sure `class(BS$StudyAreaVisitNote)=="factor"`. But, factors don't automatically drop their unused levels. This can be helpful when you are doing stuff like

```
set.seed(16)
dd<-data.frame(
    gender=sample(c("M","F"), 25, replace=T),
    age=rpois(25, 20)
)
dd

table(subset(dd, age<15)$gender)
# F M 
# 0 3
```

Here the factor remember that it had M and F's and even if the subset doesn't have any F's the levels are still retained. You may explicitly call `droplevels()` if you want to get rid of unused levels.

```
table(droplevels(subset(dd, age<15))$gender)
# M
# 3
```

(now it forgot about the F's)

So instead of `summary`, compare the results of `table` on your two data.frames.